# PlaidML accuracy not improving

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, virtualenv, plaidml

When I run my code on Colab and on my machine using the CPU the accuracy of the network improves but when running the same code using PlaidML the accuracy never improves.

My requirements.txt file is as follows:

```
scikit-learn
scikit-image
matplotlib
seaborn
ipython
jupyter
scipy
numpy
pandas
pillow
pydot
coremltools==3.0
plaidml==0.6.4
plaidbench==0.6.4
keras==2.2.4
tensorflow==1.14
```

My imports are as follows:

```
import os
os.environ["KERAS_BACKEND"] = "plaidml.keras.backend"
import keras
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator 
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import *
from keras import optimizers, callbacks
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.applications.mobilenet import MobileNet
```

There must be an issue with my requirements or my imports.

Comment: What makes you think the issue must be with requirements or imports?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Since the code works on Colab and on my machine without PlaidML my thought is that something is not setup correctly for PlaidML.  It could be something else and I am open to ideas.